# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Please help me i am Stuck

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

The Above error is comming when executing the method

```
void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    using (ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Socket localsock = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int RecLen = localsock.EndReceive(AR);
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, RecLen);
        bnrFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();                
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;                
        AddListItem("MS length:" + ms.Length + "\nMS position: " + ms.Position);            
        TrackerData data = (TrackerData)bnrFormatter.Deserialize(ms);

        if (pushToDB(data) == 1)
        {
            AddListItem("New packet data received from client of IP " + ((IPEndPoint)localsock.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString() + " and Port " + ((IPEndPoint)localsock.LocalEndPoint).Port + " .");
        }
        byte[] resBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("New packet data sent to the server!!");
        localsock.BeginSend(resBuffer, 0, resBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(EndCallback), localsock);
        localsock.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), localsock);
    }
}
```

The Error appers in line

```
TrackerData data = (TrackerData)bnrFormatter.Deserialize(ms);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.
Set the position to 0 of your memory stream and do not use your object but the object type.

```
  ms.Position = 0;
  BinaryFormatter bnrFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  TrackerData data = (TrackerDataObjectType)bnrFormatter .Deserialize(ms);
```

Comment: Yes  shreesha. can you explain me what the error about

Comment: setting Position to 0 will take you to the beginning of the stream.i thought it might solve the problem

Comment: Actually the problem is from where TrackerDataObjectType came on to the screen the class of TrackerData  is  [Serializable]
        public class TrackerData
        {
            public string PacketData { get; set; }
            public DateTime OnDate { get; set; }
        }

Comment: what value you are getting for ms.Length and ms.Position?